# Auto Refresh Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook, in the workbook I have 2 sheets called  Front Page and Drafting. Drafting worksheet is referencing some of the values in the Front Page worksheet. It is just a basic reference

I have formulas like :  ='Front Page'!D46 (in the drafting page cells to reference the cells in the Front Page)

My problem is whenever I make a change to one of the referenced cells on the front page, I need to refresh my drafting page in order to get the newly entered value. 
I need to press F9 every time I make a change in the front page to make it reflect back to Drafting Page.

I am not sure what is causing this issue? Could someone please help me fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Formulas ribbon, find the Calculation Options drop-down and make sure to select "Automatic". Then changes will reflect immediately, without pressing F9

[image]

Comment: Got it Thanks. Will accept your answer as the solution once it lets me accept.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

@teylyn have pointed out it correct, but If you would like to handle with `VBA` then you can use the below code where appropriate.

`Application.Calculate()`

Or

`Application.CalculateFull()`

Or

If you would need to forcefully make the Calculation to be Automatic then you could use the following code:

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: Yea I gave it a try as well and It worked ;). Thanks for the response mate, might use it in the future. Thank you